# Can this problem be solved using induction

Tags: calculus

Given:

> $y=(x^2-1)^n$

Can this be proven using induction taking base case $n=0$:

> $y^{(n+2)}-2xy^{(n+1)}+n(n+1)y^{(n)}=0$

I don't want a complete solution, just a hint in the right direction would do.

Comment: Better to write that as $y_n=(x^2-1)^n$ so allow for the induction. Then $y_n'=2(n-1)x(x^2-1)^{n-1}=2(n-1)xy_{n-1}$.

Comment: No, I don'y mean this way

Comment: What way? That comment doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry, i get this!